# How can I get invoices with one loc only?

Tags: sql

I have table ( aztrd)  it contains invoice deatils like itm_code , date, loc_cd ... ect

- in each in invoice they are items from loc_cd "1" and loc_cd "2" and some invoices has loc_cd   "1" only or loc_cd  "2" only

i use this query:

`SELECT tr_no,loc_cd FROM AZTRD 
WHERE LOC_CD = 1 and tr_ty = 102 and loc = 01  AND LOC_CD NOT IN (SELECT itm_cd WHERE LOC_CD = 2)
GROUP BY TR_NO,LOC_CD
ORDER BY TR_NO`

So how can I get invoices that has LOC_CD  (1) - any LOC_CD  has (1,2) I don't want them - I try it as you see but this invoice has items from 1 and have items from 2 - so I don't want it it just want only invoice has one LOC_CD not both ?

Answer (score 2):

That SQL won't even work. Please post the actual SQL you are using.

Making a lot of assumptions you might be after this:

```
SELECT tr_no,loc_cd 
FROM AZTRD WHERE LOC_CD = 1 
AND  tr_ty = 102 
AND  loc = 01 
AND  itm_cd NOT IN     
    (SELECT itm_cd FROM AZTRD WHERE LOC_CD = 2) 
ORDER BY TR_NO
```

A possibly faster way is like this:

```
SELECT tr_no,loc_cd 
FROM AZTRD D 
WHERE LOC_CD = 1 
and tr_ty = 102 
and loc = 01 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM AZTRD E WHERE E.itm_cd = D.itm_cd AND E.LOC_CD = 2) 
ORDER BY D.TR_NO
```

Comment: You deserve the credit, so I'll just comment... Much cleaner, and will *run* `;)` but you kept his subquery logic, that is *NOT* accomplishing his stated goal:  "just want only invoice has one LOC_CD not both".  How about (1) `GROUP BY TR_NO`, (2) add `HAVING MIN(LOC_CD) = MAX(LOC_CD)`, and (3) change the first line to `SELECT tr_no,MIN(loc_cd)`?

Comment: Then, with those changes, the subquery in the `WHERE` would be dropped.

Comment: I won't be offended if you post that as an answer :) It's really just a shot in the dark to see if the OP will even bother responding - often they don't.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a little hard to read, and as ElecticLlama pointed out, the SQL code you provided will not run...

But, building on ElecticLlama's interpretation, and code cleanup, (so if this helps you, UPVOTE HIS TOO), I thought these logic changes (esp. adding a `HAVING` clause), might give you your goal: "just want only invoice has one LOC_CD not both".

```
SELECT tr_no, location_code = MIN(loc_cd)
FROM AZTRD 
WHERE tr_ty = 102 
GROUP BY tr_no
HAVING MIN(loc_cd) = MAX(loc_cd)
ORDER BY tr_no
```

Hope that helps! ...let us know.